# Images in Word or Outlook get blurry when you add a border

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, images

If you have an image in your clipboard (from a screen capture tool, for example) and paste it into Word or an Outlook email, it looks fine. However if you then apply a border style to it from one of the default Picture Styles in the (Picture Tools) Format ribbon, it suddenly gets blurry. Similar problems have been reported on various forums [here](https://superuser.com/questions/118032/inserted-images-into-outlook-2007-email-blurry) and [elsewhere](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/word-2007-borders-make-pictures-blurry/f474f21d-f5a0-46d0-910c-881ee5b64c59?db=5). The usual suggestion is to:

1. [Reset the default size](https://superuser.com/a/656432/27017), or
2. [Turn Off Picture Compression](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-off-picture-compression-81a6b603-0266-4451-b08e-fc1bf58da658).

But these suggestions overlook the facts that :

1. I *want* to resize it (and can resize an un-bordered picture without blurriness).
2. Picture compression cannot be set in Outlook. (And it doesn't resolve the problem in Word anyway.)

Is there any other way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

So, I just noticed that *not all* of the Picture Styles cause the blurriness problem. The first two default ones in the Styles ribbon do, but some of the others work fine. It just took a little sleuthing to figure out that the *real* problem is **3-D Format**.

So the solution is fairly straight-forward: Open the Format Picture task pane, navigate to the 3-D Format section and click the "Reset" button. And *-POOF-* the problem disappears.[image]

Comment: "Open the Format Picture task pane" == Right click on image?

Comment: @Hannu: yes, or you can also click the little "pop-out" button at the bottom-right corner of the Picture Styles ribbon tab.